# Some Fn key combination do not work

Tags: windows-7, fn-key

I have a VIAO VPCF111FX laptop. Just three combination of <kbd>Fn</kbd> work properly like <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> (volume up) works, and the others have no effect. What should I do? Is there any driver for that?

Beside that <kbd>ASSIST</kbd>, <kbd>S1</kbd> and <kbd>VAIO</kbd> buttons do not send any signal too. (I tested it with AutoScriptWriter app)

Factory install of Windows dose not have thus issue, but I installed an orginal win7.

Comment: Is it running a factory install of Windows or did you remove some stuff/reformat it?

Comment: @Akash I installed an original copy of win7, not OEM version.

Comment: Does it has three driver listed like this `vaio event service`, `sony dll utils` and `Sony shared library`. If yes then install them in the order I write them and please reboot every installation.

Comment: Also check in `services.msc` that Vaio event service startup is automatic if not change it to automatic.

Comment: @avirk From where can I download sony dll utils?

Comment: You can see this [Sony Util](http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/swu-download.pl?mdl=PCGC1VN&upd_id=405&os_id=7) for windows XP may be work for you. Also see the [Driver](http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/swu-download.pl?mdl=VPCF111FX&upd_id=5373&os_id=45) page of your model. I will try to find the files for windows 7.

Comment: Found [Sony DLL for Vista](http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/swu-download.pl?mdl=VGNSZ460N&upd_id=2453&os_id=29) hope they will work for windows 7.

Comment: [Here](http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/swu-download.pl?mdl=VGNFE890N&upd_id=2417&os_id=29) all driver for windows vista will work like charm on Windows-7 AFAIK due to compatibility will do the rest for you. Don't forget to reboot after every installation and installation order.

Comment: @avirk Thanks a lot for your suggests. Unfortunately xp version failed to install because OS incompatibility and other two failed to install because Model incompatibility.

Comment: Have you tried them to install in compatibility mode which is provided by Windows 7

Comment: [Here](http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/39237-windows-7-sony-vaio-fe890-n.html) a user installed Windows 7 through the Vista's driver and he executed them in compatibility mode and also as Admin.

Comment: @avirk Thanks again. I will try that and will inform you if I achieve any success.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there are utilities and drivers for that. You sould have a few DVDs contaning drivers and utilities, if you don't, you can download them from the sony website (search for VIAO drivers) then enter model number.  You should see all drivers and untilities suppored by sony for your laptop.

Short answer: You need to download and install sony shared library

For Win7-64 bit: http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/swu-download.pl?mdl=VPCF111FX&upd_id=6832&os_group_id=6

For Win7-32 bit: http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/swu-download.pl?mdl=VPCF111FX&upd_id=6832&os_group_id=5

Comment: I test all of its driver with no success, do you know exactly which driver is for this issue?

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: I installed it, no thing changed.

Answer (score -1):

Pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+fn keys together will solve the problem.

Comment: Will this also make the Assist, etc. buttons work?